# Can't populate jtable with mysql "like" statement

Tags: java, mysql, jtable, sql-like, resultset

I am building an application in which you can save deals to database. I'd like to search deals in my database and populate my jtable with relevant results. I want to query my database on keyrelease event. I know it is not an efficient method but I am curious why I can't get it to work.

Below is a sample code that tries to query a database table with ID and country names. There are only 3 country names that start with "D". Somehow I can get country names printed out but can't get them to populate jtable.

The error -

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException" I can't get ResultSet rs1 into a Object[][] . It works fine if I do System.out.println(rs1.getString("Name")
```

Below is the code -

```
private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    String columnName[] = new String[] { "Name" };
    Object oss[][] = new Object[3][];
    ResultSet rs1 = null;
    int li = 0;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Url, User, Password);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * from unit.cntry WHERE Name LIKE '" + abc.getText() + "%';";
        rs1 = st.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    try {
        while (rs1.next()) {
            oss[li][0] = rs1.getString("Name");
            li++;
        }
        myTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(oss, columnName));
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs1 != null) rs1.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Any error? Also don't do `catch(Exception e){}`, you need to print the exception?

Comment: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException" I can't get ResultSet rs1 into a Object[][] . It works fine if I do System.out.println(rs1.getString("Name")

Comment: Replace `Object oss[][]=new Object[3][];` with `Object oss[][]=new Object[3][1];`. Right now you don't have the element `oss[li][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        oss[li] = new Object[1];
        oss[li][0] = rs1.getString("Name");
```

Other data structures might be more appealing.

Comment: I am using 2-D array because DefaultTableModel don't take 1-D array as parameter.